# Android Save Image to New Folder

Tags: android, string, save, directory, android-image

I'm trying to save pictures that I took awhile ago into a different folder (the folder already exists).  My manifest is up to date on permissions that I need, and I know I need to use something along the lines of:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

The following is my code.  What am I doing wrong that it won't save?   Thank you!

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

int id = viewIt.getId();

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String myDir = new String(root + "/New Directory/Folder 1/"); 
String description = "";
String filestring = arrPath[id];        
try {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), myDir, filestring, description);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
    Uri.parse("file://" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          


    }
});
```

Here are the errors from my logcat:

```
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:551)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.test.Import$ImageAdapter$2$4$1.onClick(Import.java:339)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out!  I decided to go a different route and just rename the file.  I realized that I didn't want multiples of the same image (trying to conserve sdcard space) so I did this instead:

```
int id = viewIt.getId();

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File sdddcard = new File(sdcard + "/New Directory/Folder 1/");

File from = new File(arrPath[id]);


Random generator = new Random(); 
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String filename = "ImageImport-"+ n +".jpg";

File to = new File(sdddcard,filename);

from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: Why did this get a down vote?  This worked for me.  If you have a better answer I would love to be enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

1) Folder name with space could have some problem so make sure you check if folder exist otherwise create it.

```
File file = new File(myDirPath); 
if(!file.exists()) {
  if(!file.mkdirs()){
    Log.e("TAG", "Error: You can't create folder");   
  }
}
```

2) There's probably an error but you don't see it because you catch exception but don't print it.

Try replacing this

> ```
> e.printStackTrace();
> ```

with

> Log.e("TAG", "Error: "+ e.toString());

Comment: Thank you!  I am now seeing an error.  It is telling me that my line:  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), myDir, filestring, description); is the problem.  Any idea on what way I formatted it wrong?

Comment: 04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 17:38:03.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):  at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:551)

Comment: error is on line 339 in your code. com.test.Import$ImageAdapter$2$4$1.onClick(Import.java:339). If it is the line with insert then make sure getContentResolver() isn't null.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be null.  Do I need to add something to the getContentResolver() (getContenResolver().somethingelse )?

Comment: I'm trying a to use FileoutPutStream instead, but am having troubles still.  Is it possible to go that route?

Comment: it is possible. just make sure that nothing is null. use Log or just debug at every step that you have your file and path valid. 90% of times it is the problem.